# How to display a button above a QTCaptureView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, quicktime

How can i display a button above a QTCaptureView?
I have tried to put a button above the QTCaptureView on IB but when i run it, after the QTCaptureView starts showing the iSight camera image, the button hides behind the QTCaptureView...

Comment: What kind of button are you trying to add? NSButton or something else?

Comment: It has nothing to do with layers. Read about Cocoa views and controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set `setWantsLayer:YES` in IB to both `QTCaptureView` and `NSButton`.
Not layer based views don't support overlapping.

Then after the xib is loaded the order may be not correct, so do in `awakeFromNib:`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
  [self addsubview:qtView]
  [self addsubview:button]
}
```

I am not sure if it will help, but it should help.
I had answer a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511147/drawing-a-subview-on-top-of-a-google-map-displayed-in-a-webview-on-osx/8516379#8516379)

Answer (score 0):

Like Davyd said, NSButton has nothing to do with CALayer
How do you try to change the frame of the QTCaptureView?
Please post code

Comment: just by doing the `setFrame:`

Comment: But what does that have to do with the NSButton?
Please provide some code, I don't get what you want to do.
Or at least tell me, when do you want to change the frame of the QTCaptureView, and what should happen, and what has the button to do with it

Comment: mainly i want to display a button above the QTCaptureView. If you put 1 button on IB, above the QTCaptureView, and run it, after appearing the iSight feedback on the QTCaptureView, the button will hide behind the QT. I searched around for a way to fix it and i found that setting `setWantsLayer:YES` on the `contentView` of the Window that contains the QT, the button can now be seen above the QT and it doesn't hide anymore. But i also want to change it's(QT) frame later but it's not working when i try to use `NSMakeRect(0, 0, 541, 343)`. I think it's a problem with the `setWantsLayer:YES`

Comment: if you know any other way of forcing the button to be above the QT all time tell me.

Comment: why do you even setWantsLayers:YES ?

Comment: as i said, i searched around i found out that setting `setWantsLayer:YES` would allow the button to be always above the QT.

Comment: that has nothing to do with this, you use setWantsLayers if you are working with CALayers. Post the IBAction that is being triggered from the button.

Comment: okay, so how can i force the button to be always above the QT? it's just this: `[[_outputView animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 541, 343)];`